# I have implemented ItemTouchHelper for drag and drop items from top to bottom and bottom to top in recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have implemented ItemTouchHelper for setting drag and drop from bottom to top and top to bottom when swiping is done then it should refresh the list. But the callback method is not working on which I have to refresh the list.

When I swipe my list then after swiping done it's not calling `onMoved` or `onSwiped`.

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,0) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                int position_dragged = dragged.getAdapterPosition();
                int position_target = target.getAdapterPosition();
              adapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged,position_target);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"swiped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMoved(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {
                super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(myRecyclerView);
```